# Brew Formula: How can I define external dependencies?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I’m writing [a brew formula](https://github.com/kenokenobingo/homebrew-memetap) for my own tap, having XQuartz and external sources (not available on brew) as dependencies. How can I include them in my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer on the brew discourse: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/brew-formula-how-can-i-define-external-dependencies/2358/3.

You need to install those sources by using an existing tap or creating a new one.

Comment: Please copy/paste the relevant parts here; if the linked page goes down your answer will be useless.

Comment: @bfontaine Done.